# Is it possible to group a list of tables into a custom Group in Navigation Pane using VBA in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I imported a list of table with the same prefix into the current database. I am wondering if there is a command so that I can group these tables into one custom group under the navigation pane using VBA.

**I understand there is a way to do this manually, but is it possible through VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-and-manage-custom-categories-and-groups-in-the-navigation-pane-HA001213880.aspx